# HP Probook 455 G9: Wireless rtw98 driver not working

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, hp

(NOTE: the original title of this question was "**Wi-Fi not working after motherboard replacing**", but I changed it since I discovered it was not the cause of the problem)

I have a HP Probook 455 G9 with Xubuntu 22.04 and I installed Wi-Fi drivers from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

They worked, but after a week, my PC won't ever boot. HP assistance promptly sent me a technician who replaced my laptop's motherboard. After that, my Wi-Fi does not work properly anymore: it correctly detects Wi-Fi networks, even connects with one of them for a few seconds, then it suddenly disconnects and does not even detect any network anymore.

This is the last part of the log before it stops working:

```
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: read rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: read rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: read rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: read rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: read rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: read rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: read rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: FW does not process h2c registers
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush pci txch: 0
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush pci txch: 1
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush pci txch: 2
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush pci txch: 3
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush pci txch: 8
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush pci txch: 9
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10
rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: mac init fail, ret:-110
```

I tried to run, in the rtw98 drivers folder, `sudo make uninstall` then `make` and `sudo make install`, but it did not work anyway. It says `mac init fail`, but how comes it works in a first moment, even for a short time?
I hope I don't have to reinstall Xubuntu, because it would mean to reinstall all the programs I use for work and sync a lot of stuff again.

It is probably not a hardware issue, since it properly works under Windows.

My `lshw` output also states:

```
    *-pci:0
         descrizione: PCI bridge
         prodotto: Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
         fornitore: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         id fisico: 1.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.2
         versione: 00
         larghezza: 32 bits
         orologio: 33MHz
         capacità: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configurazione: driver=pcieport
         risorse: irq:33 ioport:3000(dimensione=4096) memoria:fb600000-fb6fffff
       *-network NON RECLAMATO
            descrizione: Ethernet controller
            prodotto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            fornitore: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            id fisico: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            versione: 15
            larghezza: 64 bits
            orologio: 33MHz
            capacità: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
            configurazione: latency=0
            risorse: ioport:3000(dimensione=256) memoria:fb604000-fb604fff memoria:fb600000-fb603fff
    *-pci:1
         descrizione: PCI bridge
         prodotto: Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
         fornitore: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         id fisico: 1.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.3
         versione: 00
         larghezza: 32 bits
         orologio: 33MHz
         capacità: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configurazione: driver=pcieport
         risorse: irq:34 ioport:2000(dimensione=4096) memoria:fb500000-fb5fffff
       *-generic
            descrizione: Interfaccia Wireless
            prodotto: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            fornitore: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            id fisico: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            nome logico: wlp2s0
            versione: ff
            seriale: 10:68:38:39:3b:52
            larghezza: 32 bits
            orologio: 66MHz
            capacità: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configurazione: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=5.15.0-73-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            risorse: irq:77 ioport:2000(dimensione=256) memoria:fb500000-fb5fffff
```

Sorry for it being in Italian, but anyway I think it should be comprehensible: "NON RECLAMATO" means "UNCLAIMED" (I'm not sure it would be translated that way in English as a technical term).
So it looks like the rtw89_8852be is pointing to a generical "Wireless Interface" instead of the "RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller", I wonder if it is right... Maybe is that the problem?

Comment: Might have to remove and reinsert the wifi card, the tech may not have installed it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced my PC with another one and had the exact same bug, so it wasn't neither hardware nor firmware.

I solved by following [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-6.1/+bug/2017277). I created the `/usr/lib/modprobe.d/70-rtw89.conf` file, containing this single line:

```
options rtw89_pci disable_clkreq=y disable_aspm_l1=y disable_aspm_l1ss=y
```

Now the log errors disappeared and everything works correctly.